# Python dash gives an error in realtime update ' TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument `n_intervals`

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-dash

I ran the below code and I got the error:

```
TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument `n_intervals`
Allowed arguments: disabled, fireEvent, id, interval, setProps
```

When I ran it. I have all the particular libraries installed on my `python 2.7`.

Please find the code which I am running:

```
app.layout = html.Div
    [
        dcc.Tabs(
            tabs=[
                {'label': seclist.keys()[i],'value': i} for i in range(0, 5)
            ],
            value=0,
            id='tabs'
        ),

        html.Div([
            html.H4('TERRA Satellite Live Feed'),
            html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
            dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
            dcc.Interval(
                id='interval-component',
                interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
                n_intervals=0
            )
        ]), 

        html.Div(id='tab-output')
    ],

    style={
        'width': '80%',
        'fontFamily': 'Sans-Serif',
        'margin-left': 'auto',
        'margin-right': 'auto'
    })
print 'HI'


@app.callback(Output('tabs','value'), [Input('interval-component','n_intervals')])
def updateData(n):
    print 'yo man'
    extractData(df,axis_points)
```

Another query I have is, I see that most of the real time examples use a single graph or subplots, but is it possible to have different tabs where each tab is updated every 100 milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a version change within Dash, but I (like you) am stuck on the older version.

The fix with the older version [(found here)](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-interval-updates-issues/7015):

```
#*In Layout*
            dcc.Interval(
                id='interval-component',
                interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            )

#*Callback*
@app.callback(
    output=Output(component_id='tabs', component_property='value'),
    events=[Event('interval-component', 'interval')]
)
def updateData():
```